# SSAS model updates but Power BI report doesn't

Tags: powerbi, ssas, refresh

For the past few weeks I have been building an SSAS tabular model which has been working like a dream. I have run a refresh of the data in Visual Studio (by processing all the tables). However, the refreshed data doesn't seem to be making it to the Power BI Report. I have tried a manual refresh but nothing seems to be working.

Any hints or tips?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you deployed and refreshed the model. In VS,you will have a local instance or integrated workspace, was tha tabular middle name with your user details appended to it, not the model itself

Comment: Thanks so much @Jon for your help - you were right! The model was reading from the one with the user details rather than the actual model. Many thanks again.